# How do I calculate my average price for a share bought multiple times?

Tags: investing, calculation, shares, price, value-averaging

Let's assume below as my transactions:

```
bought 10 at 120
bought 20 at 150
sold 15 at 170
```

What will be the average price of my holdings i.e., for 18 shares.

Is it 110 ?

[image: image of OP's spreadsheet calculations]

Comment: Do you want the average price from your perspective, as opposed to the market's? If yes, then this is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sheet shows math. OK math, but probably not good accounting for taxes. 
You can set up your account for FIFO (first in first out) LIFO (last in first out) or specific shares identified by lot. Average cost basis is available, and you did the math right, but it is less common, and not a default broker choice. 
Some also offer a tax optimized sale choice, which would choose higher cost lots for short term gain, or longer term lots to capture long term cap gains.

Note: The choice has to be made with the broker prior to the sales. You don't get to choose after the fact.

Comment: OP doesn't say where they're from; but in the UK "average price" appears to be the way things are taxed ([HMRC page](https://www.gov.uk/tax-sell-shares/same-company)) -- I believe that in essence they regard the shares as "indistinguishable" so you cannot "pick" which ones to sell.

Comment: @TripeHound That would correct for Canadian tax treatment as well.

Comment: You are both right, that I should have first asked for a country tag. Although, I suppose I could have phrased the answer to be more inclusive.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Yes, in the simplest case it is the same for Canada. I'll just add that in some cases, the Adjusted Cost Base changes further based on the nature of distributions (dividend, return of capital, reinvested or not, etc.) But for no distributions it is simple enough.

Comment: I just need this for creating an app for cryptocurrency..Soon I publish in market. So I am not taking care of Tax related stuff for now atleast.